# D3 - How to append an <img> to a <td> using an each function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3, and I'm trying to append an image to a specific table cell using d3. I'm using an each function to iterate through my data where each data element is associated with a td. For the last data element I want to add an image.

Through searching I've found some code that works for adding a p element, but I can't seem to adapt it for an image. What I really don't understand is why I can change the background color of the cell in one line, but I can't append an image element with the next. What am I doing wrong?

```
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(tableData, function(d) { return d.ID; });

rows.enter()
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) { return columns.map(function(column) {
        return {column: column, value: d[column]};
    });
})
.enter()
.append("td")
.style("opacity", 0.0)
.transition()
.delay(1200)
.duration(1000)
.text(function(d) { return d.value; })
.each(function(d, i) {
    if (i == 6) {
        d3.select(this).style("background-color", "red"); // works
        d3.select(this).selectAll("img")
            .data(d.imgLink)
            .enter()
            .append("img") // doesn't append an <img> anywhere
    }
});
```

EDIT: I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atlantic_forest/n6b7t2ye/19/). The code in the fiddle differs slightly from what's posted here, but it's the same in principle. I'd like to append an image in the final column of the table using an each function.

In the fiddle, I'm also not sure why only the first cell in the last column has a red background... when I use the same code locally, all cells in the final columns are red.

Comment: Don't you need to set the `href` attribute of the img tag?

Comment: Even if I set a "src" the <img> element does not show up in the DOM.

Comment: need  some code to test. Upload a fiddle

Comment: You bind a data array of objects having properties `column` and `value`. Hence, `d.imgLink` is undefined in your callback provided to `.each()` resulting in an empty enter selection which will not append any `img`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the problem that [altocumulus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4235784/altocumulus) pointed out regarding `d.imgLink` being undefined in the callback, I also found that I needed to move my `each()` function before the `transition()`. Here is my updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atlantic_forest/n6b7t2ye/50/).